# Can't find element within easyui tree

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I have a piece of code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Post</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="any-class">
            <li id="list1">Item no.1</li>
            <li>Item no.2</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can find element "list1" by using this command jQuery('#list1')

```
jQuery('#list1').length = 1
```

but when I change class "any-class" to "easyui-tree",the element can't be found anymore.

```
jQuery('#list1').length = 0
```

Are there any trick to find element within easyui tree?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide your complete HTML code?

Comment: Hi Smit Raval, I've updated the html code

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try it with inheritance? Like the code below.

### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Post</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="easyui-tree">
            <li id="list1">Item no.1</li>
            <li>Item no.2</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

### js

```
alert(jQuery('.easyui-tree #list1').length);
```

Comment: Its result : 0 (not found)

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle? @Samuel

Comment: Sorry, what is fiddle? My goal is how to add li tag within the ul dynamically & it uses tree of easyui